# How to fix text-overflow: ellipsis not working on a select / option menu

Tags: select, drag-and-drop, option-type, word-wrap, ellipse

How can i remove option text length? text overflow is not working in option

[image]

want to fix option drop down. width will be same as select box. no matter how much text are added in option. my expectation is to add text overflow in option so that can resolve that issues.

Comment: Please use periods to end your sentences. It's difficult to figure out what you're trying to say otherwise.